# Using Adobe Air to display swf in Android 4.4 (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, flash, air

I have a android application written in java and I am a android programmer. I have few swf files that needs to be displayed in android app. With earlier versions I was able to display using webview but with post kitkat this is not possible as per multiple search across google.

If we use flash to publish Air APK project it runs the swf perfectly. Can we extract the same code to display our swf in java program as I cannot move away from java programming as there are other features around the program.

Please help as Adobe themself are successfully displaying .swf on kitkat.